# PIP and NPM install not working with fake-usergent

Tags: python, npm, pip

I have been try to install fake_useragent using both pip and npm. I can see that it's installed but the program still gives me this error Import "fake_useragent" could not be resolved. I tried many google searches and could not find any solution. I tried pip install fake_useragen, npm install fake_useragen and pip3 install fake_useragen. I also tried demoting to lower versions of python and it still does not work.

Comment: If you're having package installation issues, I recommend you read about virtual environments: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html. Using them will probably solve your problem.

Comment: You might have to add PATH of fake_useragent to Env Variables. For example there is a package in Python called Behave, it will give the same "ERROR: could not be resolved.", to fix this the path to this package has to be added to Env variables, after which you will have to restart your computer

Comment: Attempt the above and let us know what you get

Comment: @PSR Hi thank you for your response. I tried making the variable but it won't work. I set the value as the path of the folder and the name as fake_useragent. Am i missing something?

Comment: please watch a tutorial on YT on how to set an Env Variable. It is fairly straightforward. You may refer to this  as well => https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/amp/

Comment: @PSR Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @Wowz Nice to know 